# Why wont my terminal read commands like rpm?

Tags: kernel

I just recently finished a pretty poorly put together coding bootcamp and am now taking online classes. I'm currently going over linux and command line. I have a macOS Mojave 10.14.3 and oh my zsh for my framework. I'm currently learning about kernel and am trying to check the kernel on my mac but none of the command can be found.

For example:

```
rpm -qa | grep -i kernel

zsh: command not found: rpm.
```

Comment: Have you actually installed RPM? Or the other packages whose commands you aren’t able to execute?

Comment: MacOS isn't based on Linux...

Comment: Neither’s RPM (exclusively) @Mat

Comment: "... and am trying to check the kernel on my mac..." - how is installing RPM on his Mac going to help with that? @Clive

Comment: Like I said the school wasn't that great they installed most of . them for use and anytime i asked how to use they said worry about it later. So I do have some packages.

Answer (score 3):

seems like you dont have `rpm` installed in your local machine.

> `brew install rpm`